# How to sort by CLOB column with Hibernate / DB2

Tags: hibernate, sorting, db2

I'm using Hibernate 4 and DB2 10.1. When I sort an entity (`criteria.addOrder(...)`) by a property that maps to a CLOB column, I get the following error:

```
[...] could not extract ResultSet:.org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2366)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2361)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1587)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
[...]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-134, SQLSTATE=42907, SQLERRMC=TEXT7_0_0_, DRIVER=4.15.100
[...]
```

The reason is that DB2 cannot sort by CLOB columns. So the following statement will fail:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY CLOB_COLUMN;
```

One possible solution to this is to cast a `CLOB` to a `VARCHAR`for sorting. So this works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY CAST(CLOB_COLUMN AS VARCHAR(1000));
```

How can I get Hibernate to do such a special handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by subclassing `org.hibernate.criterion.Order` and overriding `toSqlString(...)`. My implementation is called `DB2Order` and delegates all calls to super except if it detects a `DB2Dialect` and one of the sorting columns is of type CLOB.

In my code I used to call:

```
if (sortProperty.isAscending()) {
     criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(sortPropertyPath));
} else {
     criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(sortPropertyPath));
}
```

Now I call:

```
if (sortProperty.isAscending()) {
     criteria.addOrder(new DB2Order(sortPropertyPath, true));
} else {
     criteria.addOrder(new DB2Order(sortPropertyPath, false));
}
```

Some details of my `DB2Order` implementation:

```
/**
 * Specialized subclass of Hibernate's {@link Order} that performs special 
 * handling for DB2 databases. The general strategy is to let the superclass 
 * perform all processing except for special cases. Special cases covered are:
 * <ul> 
 * <li>Sorting by {@code CLOB} columns. {@code CLOB} columns cannot be sorted 
 * directly by DB2, e.g. the SQL statement 
 * <p><code>SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY CLOB_COLUMN;</code>
 * <p>will fail with
 * <p><code>DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-134, SQLSTATE=42907</code>
 * <p>This class identifies sorting by CLOB columns and generates an SQL string 
 * that casts {@code CLOB} to a {@code VARCHAR} for sorting, rendering 
 * <p><code>SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY CAST(CLOB_COLUMN AS VARCHAR(1000));</code>
 * <p>(which is successfully executed by DB2).
 * <p><i>Note that this approach will trim {@code CLOB} entries that are larger 
 * than the {@code VARCHAR} casted to. So sorting may not be exact for long 
 * values.</i> 
 * </ul>
 */
public class DB2Order extends Order {
    ...    
    private static final int VARCHAR_SIZE = 1000;
    private static final String CAST_PREFIX = "CAST(";
    private static final String CAST_SUFFIX = " AS VARCHAR(" + VARCHAR_SIZE + "))";
    ...
    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
            throws HibernateException {
        if (isDB2(criteriaQuery) && isClob(criteria, criteriaQuery)) {
            return toSqlStringWithClobTypeCast(criteria, criteriaQuery);
        }
        return super.toSqlString(criteria, criteriaQuery);
    }

    private String toSqlStringWithClobTypeCast(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        String[] columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, 
            getPropertyName());
        Type type = criteriaQuery.getTypeUsingProjection(criteria, 
                getPropertyName());
        StringBuilder fragment = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            final StringBuilder expression = new StringBuilder();
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = criteriaQuery.getFactory();
            int sqlType = type.sqlTypes(factory)[i];
            boolean lower = false;
            if (isIgnoreCase()) {
                lower = sqlType == Types.VARCHAR
                        || sqlType == Types.CHAR
                        || sqlType == Types.LONGVARCHAR;
            }
            boolean clob = (sqlType == Types.CLOB);
            if (lower) {
                expression.append(factory.getDialect().getLowercaseFunction())
                    .append('(');
            }
            if (clob) {
                expression.append(CAST_PREFIX);
            }
            expression.append(columns[i]);
            if (clob) {
                expression.append(CAST_SUFFIX);
            }
            if (lower) {
                expression.append(')');
            }
            fragment.append(factory.getDialect().renderOrderByElement(
                    expression.toString(), null, isAscending() ? "asc" : "desc",
                    NullPrecedence.NONE));
            if (i < columns.length - 1) {
                fragment.append(", ");
            }
        }
        return fragment.toString();
    }

    private boolean isClob(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        String[] columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, 
                getPropertyName());
        Type type = criteriaQuery.getTypeUsingProjection(criteria, 
                getPropertyName());
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = criteriaQuery.getFactory();
            int sqlType = type.sqlTypes(factory)[i];
            if (sqlType == Types.CLOB) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isDB2(CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) {
        return criteriaQuery.getFactory().getDialect() instanceof DB2Dialect;
    }
}
```